# Why is my program only returning an initial and not the word in Python?

Tags: python, string, function, input

I am trying to write a program that requests a three-
part name and then displays the middle
name.

Repex:

```
fullname = str(input('Enter a 3-part name:'))
Roger Dupont Federer
print('Middle name:', fullname[1]
Output: R
```

However, I want to extract Dupont. What is wrong with my code?

)

Comment: I highly doubt that the output is `R`. You have to split the string before you can access words by token, otherwise it will access characters in the string.

Comment: ‘What’s wrong with my code’ appears to be that you either haven’t written ‘your code’ and have chosen not to show it, or you haven’t written any code. Without you editing your code into your question we will never know which is the correct possiblity, will we?

Comment: There is a difference between the single string `'Roger Dupont Federer'` (which `input` returns) and something like `('Roger', 'Dupost', 'Federer')` (which is what you seem to assume is returned).

Answer (score 2):

Use `split()`:

```
print(input('Enter a 3-part name:').split(' ')[1])
```

when you do `fullname[1]` you're indexing the second character not the second word